# I want to change my bundle identifier as well as product name in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have completed project but unfortunately, I have to change product name and bundle identifier also, in Xcode 6.4. How can I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change the value of *Product Name* (referenced as `PRODUCT_NAME`) in the build settings of the project or target.

[image: screen shot]

Both the *Bundle identifier* and *Bundle name* in your info plist reference this build setting, so changing it here updates both these values. I personally wouldn't change the *Bundle identifier* in the plist directly as it has a strict set of allowed characters and you can see from peoples examples it adds the `rfc1034identifier` to the setting reference which converts any invalid characters.

The default value (`$TARGET_NAME`) uses the name of the target in the left side panel, so you could also change this name.

Answer (score 4):

You can set "Product Name" Xcode Build Settings. You want to set your bundle identifier in the info.plist file for your app.

The bundle identifier in the Info.plist as ${PRODUCT_NAME} -  You can change app bundle name here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add another one to this, using **XCode 10.1**. Even when I updated the product name, bundle identifier etc - it still was showing as the old name.

There is a window to the side (I assume this is default as I've not actually changed anything) - with a Identity and Type with a field called 'name' also change this. Screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: Changing the location to "Relative to workspace" works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Project > Target > Info . Inside `Custom Target iOS Properties` go to `Bundle Name`, `Bundle identifier` and `Bundle display name` from there. You can also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118970/xcode-6-how-to-set-a-custom-bundle-identifier) for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name by updating Info.plist file, there is a field `Bundle Name` that is your application name. 
For `Bundle Identifier` you can change it through the developer account add new bundle identifier for your project. Or just change the `Bundle Identifier` in your project Info.plist file the x-Code will handle it.